# Erklärung von "ihr bestehen lassen"

Tags: grammatical-case

Kafka hat Folgendes in der Erzählung "Entschlüsse" geschrieben:

> Deshalb bleibt doch der beste Rat, alles hinzunehmen, als schwere
> Masse sich verhalten und fühle man sich selbst fortgeblasen, keinen
> unnötigen Schritt sich ablocken lassen, den anderen mit
> Tierblick anschaun, keine Reue fühlen, kurz, das, was vom Leben als
> Gespenst noch übrig ist, mit eigener Hand niederdrücken, d. h., die
> letzte grabmäßige Ruhe noch vermehren und nichts außer **ihr** mehr
> bestehen lassen.

Warum steht gegen das Ende des Satzes "ihr" statt "sie"? Ich würde denken, dieses Wort sollte eigentlich "sie" sein, also im Akkusativ, wie üblich, wenn man "lassen" so benutzt. D. h., ich glaube, er will sagen: lass nichts außer diese Ruhe mehr bestehen lassen. Korrigiere mich bitte, wenn ich irre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Der Kasus von "ihr" wird von "außer" bestimmt, und "außer" verlangt den Dativ. Die Struktur von

Ich lasse *nichts* (A) außer *ihr* (D) bestehen.

ist also dieselbe wie

Ich sehe *den Vogel* (A) auf *dem Baum* (D).

Answer (score 0):

****Dativ** ist korrekt**, wenn du "außer" als *Präposition* interpretierst. Zwar regiert sie nicht immer Dativ, aber meistens.

**Akkusativ ist korrekt**, wenn Du "außer" als *Konjunktion* interpretierst.
"außer" ist neben einer Präposition eine spezielle Konjunktion, bei der Kongruenz mit dem Kopf der Nominalphrase (nichts) herrscht.

Dementsprechend ist beides richtig:

> und nichts (akk) außer (präp) ihr (dat)
> und nichts (akk) außer (konj) sie (akk)

Es ist deine Entscheidung, welches "außer" du nutzt.

Comment: Danke, ja, ich war davon ausgegangen, dass dieser Gebrauch von "außer" der zweiten Interpretation entsprechen müsste. Die erste war mir nicht eingefallen.